# Restful Authentication Action Controller: Exception caught problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When login fails, it redirects to session path and i get that Exception caught error and it says

> Unknown action No action responded to
>   show. Actions: accessdenied,
>   checkroles, create, destroy, new,
>   renderoptionalerrorfile,
>   rolerequirements, and
>   role_requirements=

**sessions_controller**

```
def new
      end

      def create
        logout_keeping_session!
        user = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:password])
        if user
          # Protects against session fixation attacks, causes request forgery
          # protection if user resubmits an earlier form using back
          # button. Uncomment if you understand the tradeoffs.
          # reset_session
          self.current_user = user
          new_cookie_flag = (params[:remember_me] == "1")
          handle_remember_cookie! new_cookie_flag
          redirect_back_or_default('/')
          flash[:notice] = "Logged in successfully"
        else
          note_failed_signin
          @login       = params[:login]
          @remember_me = params[:remember_me]
          render :action => 'new'
        end
      end
protected
  # Track failed login attempts
  def note_failed_signin
    flash[:error] = "Couldn't log you in as '#{params[:login]}'"
    logger.warn "Failed login for '#{params[:login]}' from #{request.remote_ip} at #{Time.now.utc}"
  end
end
```

**routes**

```
  map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'
  map.login '/login', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
  map.register '/register', :controller => 'users', :action => 'create'
  map.signup '/signup', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new'
  map.resources :users

  map.resource :session
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a `redirect_to` instead of a render?

Upon further inspection, this might have to do with your `map.resource` call. When using a singular `map.resource` (instead of plural), no default route is created for `index`.

You might want to do a `rake:routes` to see your available routes, and check the info for `map.resource` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html).

Comment: redirect_to ('/login') works but what is wrong with render? I dont wan't to play with original codes.thanks

Comment: i created show.html.erb and it looks fine now. Is this my problem or plugins to  create necessary files ?

Comment: No, it was your mistake. You need to define the view that you want to render. Rails will look in the controller for the action you requested (show), if it doesn't find the action, it will assume that you have a view (show.html.erb), if that fails, it will complain that it can't find 'show' in your controller.